# Value of type 'AnyHashable' has no subscripts while moving the project from objective c to swift

Tags: ios, swift, migration

I am actually migrating my objective c project to swift, where in i am not that familiar with swift too. i am getting *"Value of type 'AnyHashable' has no subscripts"* error in all the `columnHeights`. basically this class is one of the class among designing the ui which displays in pintrest format. Error at this line ->    `columnHeights[section][idx] = NSNumber(value: Float(top))`

Xcode  = 10.3
swift  = 5

```
// MARK: - Methods to Override
override func prepare() {
    super.prepare()

    headersAttribute.removeAll()
    footersAttribute.removeAll()
    unionRects.removeAll()
    columnHeights.removeAll()
    allItemAttributes.removeAll()
    sectionItemAttributes.removeAll()

    let numberOfSections = collectionView?.numberOfSections
    if numberOfSections == 0 {
        return
    }

    assert(delegate is CHTCollectionViewDelegateWaterfallLayout ?? false, "UICollectionView's delegate should conform to CHTCollectionViewDelegateWaterfallLayout protocol")
    assert(self.columnCount > 0 || delegate?.responds(to: #selector(CHTCollectionViewDelegateWaterfallLayout.collectionView(_:layout:columnCountForSection:))) ?? false, "UICollectionViewWaterfallLayout's columnCount should be greater than 0, or delegate must implement columnCountForSection:")

    // Initialize variables
    var idx = 0

    for section in 0..<(numberOfSections ?? 0) {
        let columnCount = self.columnCount(forSection: section)
        var sectionColumnHeights = [AnyHashable](repeating: 0, count: columnCount)
        for idx in 0..<columnCount {
            sectionColumnHeights.append(NSNumber(value: 0))
        }
        columnHeights.append(sectionColumnHeights)
    }
    // Create attributes
    var top: CGFloat = 0
    var attributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes?

    for section in 0..<(numberOfSections ?? 0) {
        /*
         * 1. Get section-specific metrics (minimumInteritemSpacing, sectionInset)
         */
        var minimumInteritemSpacing: CGFloat
        if delegate?.responds(to: #selector(UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout.collectionView(_:layout:minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt:))) ?? false {
            if let collectionView = collectionView {
                minimumInteritemSpacing = delegate?.collectionView?(collectionView, layout: self, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt: section) ?? 0.0
            }
        } else {
            minimumInteritemSpacing = self.minimumInteritemSpacing
        }

        var columnSpacing = minimumColumnSpacing
        if delegate?.responds(to: #selector(CHTCollectionViewDelegateWaterfallLayout.collectionView(_:layout:minimumColumnSpacingForSectionAt:))) ?? false {
            columnSpacing = delegate?.collectionView?(collectionView, layout: self, minimumColumnSpacingForSectionAt: section) ?? 0.0
        }

        var sectionInset: UIEdgeInsets
        if delegate?.responds(to: #selector(UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout.collectionView(_:layout:insetForSectionAt:))) ?? false {
            if let collectionView = collectionView, let collection = delegate?.collectionView?(collectionView, layout: self, insetForSectionAt: section) {
                sectionInset = collection
            }
        } else {
            sectionInset = self.sectionInset
        }

        let width = (collectionView?.bounds.size.width ?? 0.0) - sectionInset.left - sectionInset.right
        let columnCount = self.columnCount(forSection: section)
        let itemWidth = CHTFloorCGFloat((width - CGFloat((columnCount - 1)) * columnSpacing) / CGFloat(columnCount))

        /*
         * 2. Section header
         */
        var headerHeight: CGFloat
        if delegate?.responds(to: #selector(CHTCollectionViewDelegateWaterfallLayout.collectionView(_:layout:heightForHeaderInSection:))) ?? false {
            headerHeight = delegate?.collectionView?(collectionView, layout: self, heightForHeaderInSection: section) ?? 0.0
        } else {
            headerHeight = self.headerHeight
        }

        var headerInset: UIEdgeInsets
        if delegate?.responds(to: #selector(CHTCollectionViewDelegateWaterfallLayout.collectionView(_:layout:insetForHeaderInSection:))) ?? false {
            if let collection = delegate?.collectionView?(collectionView, layout: self, insetForHeaderInSection: section) {
                headerInset = collection
            }
        } else {
            headerInset = self.headerInset
        }

        top += headerInset.top

        if headerHeight > 0 {
            attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forSupplementaryViewOfKind: CHTCollectionElementKindSectionHeader, with: IndexPath(item: 0, section: section))
            attributes?.frame = CGRect(x: headerInset.left, y: top, width: (collectionView?.bounds.size.width ?? 0.0) - (headerInset.left + headerInset.right), height: headerHeight)

            if let attributes = attributes {
                headersAttribute[NSNumber(value: section)] = attributes
            }
            if let attributes = attributes {
                allItemAttributes.append(attributes)
            }

            top = attributes?.frame.maxY ?? 100 + headerInset.bottom
        }

        top += sectionInset.top
        for idx in 0..<columnCount {
           columnHeights[section][idx] = NSNumber(value: Float(top))

        }

        /*
         * 3. Section items
         */
        let itemCount = collectionView?.numberOfItems(inSection: section)
        var itemAttributes = [AnyHashable](repeating: 0, count: itemCount ?? 0)

        // Item will be put into shortest column.
        for idx in 0..<(itemCount ?? 0) {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(item: idx, section: section)
            let columnIndex = nextColumnIndex(forItem: idx, inSection: section)
            let xOffset = sectionInset.left + (itemWidth + columnSpacing) * CGFloat(columnIndex)
           swift let yOffset = CGFloat((columnHeights[section][columnIndex] as? NSNumber)?.floatValue)
            var itemSize: CGSize? = nil
            if let collectionView = collectionView {
                itemSize = delegate?.collectionView?(collectionView, layout: self, sizeForItemAt: indexPath)
            }
            var itemHeight: CGFloat = 0
            if (itemSize?.height ?? 0.0) > 0 && (itemSize?.width ?? 0.0) > 0 {
                itemHeight = CHTFloorCGFloat((itemSize?.height ?? 0.0) * itemWidth / (itemSize?.width ?? 0.0))
            }

            attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)
            attributes?.frame = CGRect(x: xOffset, y: yOffset, width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight)
            if let attributes = attributes {
                itemAttributes.append(attributes)
            }
            if let attributes = attributes {
                allItemAttributes.append(attributes)
            }
            columnHeights[section][columnIndex] = NSNumber(value: Float(attributes?.frame.maxY + minimumInteritemSpacing))
        }

        sectionItemAttributes.append(itemAttributes)

        /*
         * 4. Section footer
         */
        var footerHeight: CGFloat
        let columnIndex = longestColumnIndex(inSection: section)
        if ((columnHeights[section] as? [Any])?.count ?? 0) > 0 {
            top = CGFloat((columnHeights[section][columnIndex] as? NSNumber)?.floatValue) - minimumInteritemSpacing + sectionInset.bottom
        } else {
            top = 0
        }

        if delegate?.responds(to: #selector(CHTCollectionViewDelegateWaterfallLayout.collectionView(_:layout:heightForFooterInSection:))) ?? false {
            footerHeight = delegate?.collectionView?(collectionView, layout: self, heightForFooterInSection: section) ?? 0.0
        } else {
            footerHeight = self.footerHeight
        }

        var footerInset: UIEdgeInsets
        if delegate?.responds(to: #selector(CHTCollectionViewDelegateWaterfallLayout.collectionView(_:layout:insetForFooterInSection:))) ?? false {
            if let collection = delegate?.collectionView?(collectionView, layout: self, insetForFooterInSection: section) {
                footerInset = collection
            }
        } else {
            footerInset = self.footerInset
        }

        top += footerInset.top

        if footerHeight > 0 {
            attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forSupplementaryViewOfKind: CHTCollectionElementKindSectionFooter, with: IndexPath(item: 0, section: section))
            attributes?.frame = CGRect(x: footerInset.left, y: top, width: (collectionView?.bounds.size.width ?? 0.0) - (footerInset.left + footerInset.right), height: footerHeight)

            if let attributes = attributes {
                footersAttribute[NSNumber(value: section)] = attributes
            }
            if let attributes = attributes {
                allItemAttributes.append(attributes)
            }

            top = attributes?.frame.maxY + footerInset.bottom
        }

        for idx in 0..<columnCount {
            columnHeights[section][idx] = NSNumber(value: Float(top))
        }
        // end of for (NSInteger section = 0; section < numberOfSections; ++section)
    }

    // Build union rects
    idx = 0
    let itemCounts = allItemAttributes.count
    while idx < itemCounts {
        var unionRect = (allItemAttributes[idx] as? UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes)?.frame
        let rectEndIndex = min(idx + unionSize, itemCounts)

        for i in idx + 1..<rectEndIndex {
            unionRect = unionRect?.union((allItemAttributes[i] as? UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes)?.frame)
        }

        idx = rectEndIndex

        unionRects.append(NSValue(cgRect: unionRect ?? CGRect.zero))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the benefits of Swift is that it's not mandatory to use objects (reference types) in collections.

As the name implies `columnHeights` seems to be a nested array of `CGFloat` instances.

Declare it

```
var columnHeights = [[CGFloat]]()
```

and populate it

```
let sectionColumnHeights = [CGFloat](repeating: 0.0, count: columnCount)
columnsHeights.append(sectionColumnHeights)
```

In all other occurrences of `columnHeights` remove the creation of `NSNumber` objects and use `CGFloat` directly

Answer (score 0):

// First you have to understand what is subscript ?

// - Subscript is used to access object value without calling method

**Here is small demo maybe its useful for understading.**

```
class Demo {
  var testArry = ["A","B","C","D"]
  subscript(_ index:Int) -> String {
    return testArry[index]
  }
}
let ob1 = Demo()
print(ob1[0])
print(ob1[1])
```